# Name for a control with a dropdown, text boxes, and a list

Tags: forms, terminology, controls

I'm creating a control with a dropdown, text boxes, and a list; it's going to look somewhat like this:

[image]

The text boxes are fixed (no matter what is selected, it would always be the same text boxes).

When you click on the `+` button, the values of the text boxes will be added to the list. The category of the values added will be the option selected from the dropdown. That same category would then be removed from the options.

Clicking on the `x` button on the other hand would remove the item from the list and add the category back to the dropdown options.

Is there a generic name for this kind of collective controls? If there's not, what would be a good name for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The general term is *Selection Dependent Inputs*.

LukeW speaks on these, often in the context of [radio buttons that expose other choices](https://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?764). It's an older piece, but still quite relevant.

Comment: The text boxes are actually fixed, it doesn't depend on the selection. The selection just lets you add the values of the text boxes with the selected option as its category.

Comment: ah, i see. The definition as I know it still stands, as they work together. Thanks for clarity.

Comment: Just saw the article/post. Really helpful! Thanks